# Prove that if the image $f \left( \Omega \right)$ is compact in the $w$-plane, then it must be a single point

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:D \to \mathbb{C}$ be analytic on the domain $D$ (open and connected). Prove that if the image $f \left( \Omega \right)$ is compact in the $w$-plane, then it must be a single point; that is $f$ is constant.

I'm trying to prove that $\left|f(z) \right|$ assumes its maximum modulus on the image $f \left(\Omega \right)$ (i.e. there exists a point $z_0 \in \Omega$ such that $\left|f(z) \right| \leqslant \left|f(z_0) \right|$ for every $z \in \Omega$), so that I may apply the "Strong Maximum Modulus Principle", to conclude that $f$ is constant.

The Strong Maximum Modulus Principle states: Let $f$ be a nonconstant analytic function defined in a plane domain $\Omega$. Then $f$ does not assume its maximum modulus at any point of $\Omega$.

How do we show that $\left|f(z) \right|$ assumes its max on a compact set?

Comment: So I guess you aren't allowed to use the open mapping theorem :)

Comment: @Ant nope!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $|\cdot| : f(\Omega) \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ is a continuous function on a compact set, therefore it attains a maximum at a point $w\in f(\Omega)$. Take $z_0$ to be any point in $\Omega$ such that $f(z_0) = w$.